# Circuit Analysis With Non-Ideal Diodes

Tags: diodes, circuit-analysis

I have seen how to do circuit analysis with ideal diodes, that is replace forward-biased diodes with connections and replace reverse-biased diodes with gaps. But the problem is that I want to know how to analize real circuits that contain non-ideal diodes. How do I do so?

I need a few leads.

**EDIT**

See comments.

Comment: SPICE will simulate circuits using non-ideal components.

Comment: That is the problem... I am writing a simulation. I can't use SPICE

Comment: Why didn't you mention that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want the simplifications, you have to fall back to the general model of a diode:

$$
I = I_o \left( e^{\frac{eV}{nkT}}-1 \right)
$$

This equation relates the diode current to the diode voltage (it's V-I characteristic)

- Io - is the diode reverse saturation current
- k - Boltzmann's constant = 1.38e-23 Joules per Kelvin
- T - Analysis temperature (Kelvin)
- e - Magnitude of electric charge
- n - Ideality factor (for silicon diodes, n=2 for small currents and approaches n=1 for large currents; in theory should always = 1)

You can now solve your circuit via the system of equations that it produces. Although you now have continuous V-I functions to describe your elements, a closed-form solution is not always guaranteed to exist.

It is often necessary to use an iterative solution technique such as Newton-Raphson to approximate/approach the answer. This is what SPICE solvers do in the general case... and why they ask you for initial conditions (which can dramatically speed up the solution time).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use one of the mathematical models of varying complexity (see e.g. [Diode Modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling)), if you are using e.g. Matlab/Scilab, etc.
Or as Leon suggests use ready made SPICE models and simulate your circuit in something like LTspice.

Or of course you could build and analyse your circuit directly.

Answer (score 0):

For a real basic circuits(probably just one diode on the circuit), you could use graphical approaches as a load line. For more complex circuit I concur that simulation is the method to use because with analytical approaches sooner or later you will run into a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) from the diodes I-V characteristics therefore a numerical approach is needed which is basically what the simulator does.